# why my text is not displayed while centering the text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

my `div` text is not displayed while centering my `div` text.I assign `width` to a `div`.Text should come on `next` line.

here is my code

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue
}
.centered {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  background: red; /* not necessary just to see the result clearly */
}

.abc{
  background: #fff;
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  line-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="centered">
  <div class="abc">This text is centered horizontally and vertically</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you need to post a [mcve] in your question, not a third party site. Second, I see your text in your example.

Comment: `whole ` text is not displayed

Comment: complete text is this `This text is centered horizontally and vertically`

Comment: @j08691 there is a big line-height creating the issue, so you don't see only a part of the text

Answer (score 1):

The `line height` is causing the issue, when you have a line break the next line will be after `400px` but your div is only `400px` thus you will have a overflow since the height of the content is `800px` (2 lines). Remove `line-height` and apply the center inside the div instead. `Line-height` is useful to center only one line of text.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  background: blue
}

.centered {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;/* not necessary just to see the result clearly */
}

.abc {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="abc">This text is centered horizontally and vertically</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height: 400px;` style in your `abc` class is causing the second line to disappear. It's going below the display and out of sight. Removing `line-height` will bring the text back, but your text will be at the top of your `abc` container. You can vertically center your text a number of ways. I would recommend wrapping your text, 'This text is centered horizontally and vertically', in a `<p>` tag, then applying the following CSS:

```
.abc{
    background: #fff;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    position: relative;
}

.abc > p {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="abc">
    <p>This text is centered horizontally and vertically</p>
</div>
```

Check out this page for more information on how this works: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/. It will also give more examples on centering text.